# need to populate json array of objects for each object of json array from another json array of objects in angular js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

In my Angularjs application, I have the following json :

$scope.listA =

```
[
  {
    "bId":777,
    "cId":4,
    "ctNm":"Software"
  },
  {
    "bId":777,
    "cId":2,
    "ctNm":"Hardware"
  },
  {
    "bId":777,
    "cId":1,
    "ctNm":"Malware"
  }
]
```

And I need to convert this array in such a way that each json object of the array should contain `items` array of objects.

The logic to populate this `items` array of objects for each of this `$scope.listA` json object is to go and check in `$scope.listB` array of json objects, if that particular `cId` exist. If yes, keep all those json objects of `$scope.listB` under `items` array of each object in `$scope.listA`.

$scope.listB =

```
 [
  {
    "bId":0,
    "cId":2,
    "clsxId":24,
    "ctNm":"Hardware",
    "clNm":"Out 1"
  },
  {
    "bId":0,
    "cId":1,
    "clsxId":99,
    "ctNm":"Malware",
    "clNm":"Srv"
  },
  {
    "bId":0,
    "cId":2,
    "clsxId":26,
    "ctNm":"Hardware",
    "clNm":"Buss"
  },
  {
    "bId":0,
    "cId":2,
    "clsxId":67,
    "ctNm":"Hardware",
    "clNm":"Pait"
  }
]
```

So the finally modified `$scope.listA`, should be as shown below :

```
[
  {
    "bId":777,
    "cId":4,
    "ctNm":"Software",
    "items":[

    ]
  },
  {
    "bId":777,
    "cId":2,
    "ctNm":"Hardware",
    "items":[
      {
        "bId":0,
        "cId":2,
        "clsxId":24,
        "ctNm":"Hardware",
        "clNm":"Out 1"
      },
      {
        "bId":0,
        "cId":2,
        "clsxId":26,
        "ctNm":"Hardware",
        "clNm":"Buss"
      },
      {
        "bId":0,
        "cId":2,
        "clsxId":67,
        "ctNm":"Hardware",
        "clNm":"Pait"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "bId":777,
    "cId":1,
    "ctNm":"Malware",
    "items":[
      {
        "bId":0,
        "cId":1,
        "clsxId":99,
        "ctNm":"Malware",
        "clNm":"Srv"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The solution in either under score or in angular js util functions, both are fine for me. I prefer not to use for loop any other way is fine, foreach, map, etc

Comment: please post some of your effort .

Comment: I tried with angular. forEach, inside that I am using listB.map, to get all the matching cIds and pushing all these matching indexes into an array and then iterating lstA, inside again I have foreach of lisB to push all the matching indexes, here for index I am using count variable to increment. But I felt there must some smart and simple way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for (var a = 0; a < $scope.listA.length; a++) {
    var itemInA = $scope.listA[a];
    itemInA.items = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < $scope.listB.length; b++) {
        var itemInB = $scope.listB[b];
        if (itemInA.cId === itemInB.cId) {
            itemInA.items.push(itemInB);
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through each of the items in your `$scope.listA` and add a `items` array to it. Then it will loop through each item in `$scope.listB` and if the item from `$scope.listB` has the same `cId` as the current item in `$scope.listA`, then it will push it onto the `items` array of the current item in `$scope.listA`.

See this working example, which will print the resulting listA out to the console log.

```js
var listA = [{
  "bId": 777,
  "cId": 4,
  "ctNm": "Software"
}, {
  "bId": 777,
  "cId": 2,
  "ctNm": "Hardware"
}, {
  "bId": 777,
  "cId": 1,
  "ctNm": "Malware"
}];

var listB = [{
  "bId": 0,
  "cId": 2,
  "clsxId": 24,
  "ctNm": "Hardware",
  "clNm": "Out 1"
}, {
  "bId": 0,
  "cId": 1,
  "clsxId": 99,
  "ctNm": "Malware",
  "clNm": "Srv"
}, {
  "bId": 0,
  "cId": 2,
  "clsxId": 26,
  "ctNm": "Hardware",
  "clNm": "Buss"
}, {
  "bId": 0,
  "cId": 2,
  "clsxId": 67,
  "ctNm": "Hardware",
  "clNm": "Pait"
}];


for (var a = 0; a < listA.length; a++) {
    var itemInA = listA[a];
    itemInA.items = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < listB.length; b++) {
        var itemInB = listB[b];
        if (itemInA.cId === itemInB.cId) {
            itemInA.items.push(itemInB);
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(listA, null, 2));
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "bId": 777,
    "cId": 4,
    "ctNm": "Software",
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "bId": 777,
    "cId": 2,
    "ctNm": "Hardware",
    "items": [
      {
        "bId": 0,
        "cId": 2,
        "clsxId": 24,
        "ctNm": "Hardware",
        "clNm": "Out 1"
      },
      {
        "bId": 0,
        "cId": 2,
        "clsxId": 26,
        "ctNm": "Hardware",
        "clNm": "Buss"
      },
      {
        "bId": 0,
        "cId": 2,
        "clsxId": 67,
        "ctNm": "Hardware",
        "clNm": "Pait"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "bId": 777,
    "cId": 1,
    "ctNm": "Malware",
    "items": [
      {
        "bId": 0,
        "cId": 1,
        "clsxId": 99,
        "ctNm": "Malware",
        "clNm": "Srv"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: In some post I read, using for loop in angularjs is not  recommended. Could you please do the same with angular.foreach, because if you use angular for each then we need to manually compute index for each iteration, if I go with your solution and I am little concern with that.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/3). Depending on the actual content of the loop, angular's foreach is actually around 84% slower than just using a native for loop. There's no need to add overhead of a library method when you can do it just as easily with native code.

Comment: Or [here](https://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/172) is another more recent comparison, showing that angular's forEach is actually the slowest of 9 different methods of for looping.

Comment: yes, I could able to recollect that suggestion not use for loop is in handling promises when we need to make multiple http requests at a time, etc. But here as there are no promises, http requests, ect I feel your solution is the best and also as per the references that you have provided. So I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
$scope.listA.forEach(function(aItem){
 aItem.Items =[];
 aItem.Items.addRange($scope.listB.where(function(bItem){return aItem.cId == bItem.cId;}));
});
```

here, I have used some extensions, I created for javascript array

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "addRange", {
 value: function (values) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        this.push(values[i]);
    }
    return this;
  }, enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "where", {
 value: function (Predicate) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (Predicate(this[i])) arr.push(this[i]);
    }
    return arr;
  }, enumerable: false
});
```

it is bit friendly for c# developer to use it like lambda expression

Comment: u can use native for loop in apposed to `forEach` as suggested by @Madasu K